# ANT BUILD ERROR : failed to create task or type testng

Tags: ant, selenium-webdriver, build.xml

> Hello, the problem is ,that i cannot trigger ANT run command in my
>   project , it gives me error. when i trigger ANT clean and ANT compile
>   , BUILD SUCCESS.

**BUILD.XML CODE ERROR LINES**
Getting the error on line :2

```
<!-- run -->
<target name="run" depends="compile">
<testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="suite1" outputDir="test-output" >  
<xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="TestNG.xml" />
</testng>
<!--suite 1 begin -->
<property name="suite.web.CopyRegressionCustomer" value="CopyRegressionCustomer" />
<testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="CopyRegressionCustomer" outputDir="test-output" >
<xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="TestNG.xml" />
</testng>
<antcall target="testngReportCopy">
<param name="testngDir" value="${testng.report.dir}${suite.web.CopyRegressionCustomer}"/>
 </antcall>
```

**ERROR LOG:
Problem: failed to create task or type testng
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.**

**FULL BUILD.xml CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="projectName" default="clean" basedir="."> <!-- dot indicates that basedir is pointing towards project root directory -->

 <!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
 <property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}" />
 <property name="ws.jars" value="/Users/mac/Downloads/selenium-2.47.1" />
 <property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
 <property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
 <property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>

 <echo> value of base dir = ${basedir} </echo>

 <!-- properties for copying the results -->
 <tstamp>
 <format property="year" pattern="yyyy" />
 <format property="DSTAMP" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
 <format property="TSTAMP" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
 <format property="dateversion" pattern="yyyy.MM.dd.HH:mm:ss" />
 <format property="time.stamp" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss aa_"/>
 </tstamp>

 <property name="testng.report.dir" value="${ws.home}/testngReports/${time.stamp}"/>
 <property name="testngXslt.report.dir" value="${ws.home}/testngXsltReports/${time.stamp}"/>

 <!-- ====== For setting the classpath ==== -->
 <target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
 <path id="classpath_jars">
 <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes = "*.jar"/>
 </path>
 <pathconvert pathsep=":"
 property="test.classpath"
 refid="classpath_jars" />

 </target>

 <!-- ============ Initializing other stuff =========== -->
 <target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
 <tstamp>
 <format property="start.time" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy (HH-mm-ss)"/>
 </tstamp>
 <condition property="ANT"
 value="$(env.ANT_HOME)/bin/ant.bat"
 else="$(env.ANT_HOME)/bin/ant">
 <!-- os family="windows" /-->
 <os family="mac" />
 </condition>



 <!--
 <taskdef name="testng" classpath="/Users/mac/Downloads/selenium-2.47.1" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" /> 
 <!- use direct path for classpath if you don't prefer to use 'lib' directory: classpath="/Users/yash/Documents/Jar Files/testng-6.8.jar" ->
 <taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
 <classpath>
 <pathelement location="./lib/testng.jar"/>
 </classpath>
 </taskdef>
 -->

 </target>

 <target name="all">
 </target>

 <!-- cleaning the destination folders -->
 <target name="clean">
 <echo message="deleting existing build directory"/>
 <delete dir="${test.dest}"/>
 </target>

 <!-- target for compiling the java files -->
 <target name="compile" depends="init, clean">
 <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
 <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
 </delete>
 <echo message="making directory....."/>
 <mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
 <echo message="classpath-------: ${test.classpath}"/>
 <echo message="compiling....."/>
 <javac
 debug="true"
 destdir="${test.dest}"
 srcdir="${test.src}"
 classpath="${test.classpath}"
 includeantruntime="true"/>
 </target>

 <!-- build -->
 <target name="build" depends="init">
 </target>

 <!-- ========== Test executions & Generating reports using Testng utility for multiple suites ============== -->
 <!-- run -->
 <target name="run" depends="compile">
    <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="suite1" outputDir="test-output" >
     <xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="TestNG.xml" />
     </testng>
 <!--suite 1 begin -->
 <property name="suite.web.CopyRegressionCustomer" value="CopyRegressionCustomer" />
 <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="CopyRegressionCustomer" outputDir="test-output" >
 <xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="TestNG.xml" />
 </testng>
 <antcall target="testngReportCopy">
 <param name="testngDir" value="${testng.report.dir}${suite.web.CopyRegressionCustomer}"/>
 </antcall> 

 <!--suite 2 begin -->
 <property name="suite.web.Copy2RegressionCustomer" value="Copy2RegressionCustomer" />
 <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="Copy2RegressionCustomer" outputDir="test-output" >
 <xmlfileset dir="." includes="webSuites/Copy2RegressionCustomer.xml" />
 </testng>
 <antcall target="testngReportCopy">
 <param name="testngDir" value="${testng.report.dir}${suite.web.Copy2RegressionCustomer}"/>
 </antcall> 

 </target>

 <target name="testngReportCopyAndReportParser">
 <!-- Copy to TestNG report directory-->
 <mkdir dir="${testngDir}">
 </mkdir>

 <!-- to copy previous suite result to TestNG report directory -->
 <copy todir="${testngDir}">
 <fileset dir="test-output"/>
 </copy> <!-- end of Testng Report -->
 </target>

 <!-- ========== Test executions & Generating reports using Testng XSLT utility for multiple suites ============== -->
 <!-- run -->
 <target name="runAsTestngXslt" depends="compile">

 <!--suite 1 begin -->
 <property name="suite.web.CopyRegressionCustomer" value="CopyRegressionCustomer" />
 <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="CopyRegressionCustomer" outputDir="test-output" >
 <xmlfileset dir="." includes="webSuites/CopyRegressionCustomer.xml" />
 </testng>
 <antcall target="testngXsltReportCopy">
 <param name="testngXsltDir" value="${testngXslt.report.dir}${suite.web.CopyRegressionCustomer}"/>
 </antcall> 

 <!--suite 2 begin -->
 <property name="suite.web.Copy2RegressionCustomer" value="Copy2RegressionCustomer" />
 <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="Copy2RegressionCustomer" outputDir="test-output" >
 <xmlfileset dir="." includes="webSuites/Copy2RegressionCustomer.xml" />
 </testng>
 <antcall target="testngXsltReportCopy">
 <param name="testngXsltDir" value="${testngXslt.report.dir}${suite.web.Copy2RegressionCustomer}"/>
 </antcall> 

 </target>

 <target name="testngXsltReportCopyAndReportParser">
 <!-- Copy to TestNG report directory-->
 <mkdir dir="${testngXsltDir}">
 </mkdir>

 <!-- to copy previous suite result to TestngXslt report folder -->
 <xslt in="${ws.home}/test-output/testng-results.xml" style="src/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
 out="${testngXsltDir}/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">

 <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${testngXsltDir}" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" expression="true" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" />
 </xslt> <!-- end of TestngXslt Report -->
 </target>

 <path id="test.c">
 <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar">
 <include name="mail.jar"/>
 <include name="activation-1.0.2.jar"/>
 </fileset>
 </path>

 <!-- ========== Generating reports using Testng XSLT utility for single suite only ============== -->
 <target name="report" depends="run">
 <!-- TestngXslt report -->
 <mkdir dir="${testngXslt.report.dir}">
 </mkdir>

 <!-- to copy previous suite result to TestngXslt report folder -->
 <xslt in="${ws.home}/test-output/testng-results.xml" style="src/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
 out="${testngXslt.report.dir}/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">

 <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${testngXslt.report.dir}" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" expression="true" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" />
 </xslt> <!-- end of TestngXslt Report -->
 </target>

 <target name="RunAndViewReport" depends="report">
 <exec executable="${browser}" spawn="yes">
 <arg line="'file:///${testngXslt.report.dir}/index.html'" />
 </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="sendMail" depends="RunAndViewReport">
 <zip destfile="${testngXslt.report.dir}/Report.zip" basedir="${testngXslt.report.dir}"/>
 <mail mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" mailport="465" subject="Notification of TESTNG build result" ssl="false" user="automationmoolya@gmail.com" password="moolya@universe">
 <from address="automationmoolya@gmail.com"/>
 <to address="yagnesh@moolya.com"/>
 <message>The build has finished. A details report of this build is attached</message>
 <attachments>
 <fileset dir="testngXslt.report.dir">
 <include name="**/*.zip"/>
 </fileset>
 </attachments>
 </mail>
 </target>

 <target name="install-jars" description="Install ANT optional jars">
 <get dest="${ws.home}/lib/mail.jar" src="file:///${ws.home}/lib/mail.jar"/>
 <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar">
 <include name="mail.jar"/>
 <include name="activation-1.0.2.jar"/>
 </fileset>
 </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at your ant-script, it use to define a TestNG ant task as:

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="testng.jar"/>
```

But in your case, you have this definition commented:

```
<!--
<taskdef name="testng" classpath="/Users/mac/Downloads/selenium-2.47.1" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" /> 
<!- use direct path for classpath if you don't prefer to use 'lib' directory: classpath="/Users/yash/Documents/Jar Files/testng-6.8.jar" ->
<taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
<classpath>
<pathelement location="./lib/testng.jar"/>
</classpath>
</taskdef>
-->
```

You need to uncomment it or add a new one defenition to your script.

Comment: <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="/Users/mac/Downloads/selenium-2.47.1"/> 

It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: seems to me, you need a <taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask"> to be uncommented and then pointed to an existing testng lib

Comment: taskdef class org.testng.TestNGAntTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Now,getting this error.

Comment: make sure, you have a testng.jar with location ./lib/testng.jar, or try to define it without a classname, as it made in <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="testng.jar"/>

Comment: @stanisiav please check my answer .

Comment: it would be better, if you'll be editing your post, not adding an answer, due to stackoverflow rules.
Could you comment it back and just add a line <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="/Users/mac/Downloads/selenium-2.47.1/testng-6.8.5.jar"/>

Comment: and one more, try to make the names be the same, because now it's a TestNG and testng.

Comment: It did gave me result :)

But build Failed with error 

The following error occurred while executing this line:
Target "testngReportCopy" does not exist in the project "Framework".

Comment: sure, you don't have it. suppose, you need to rename testngReportCopyAndReportParser task to testngReportCopy, they look very similar.

Comment: stanislav it worked for me :)
Thanks a lot for your help .
I am a beginner to this. what i was taught was just to copy BUILD.xml from internet and make few changes ,your project will run.Thanks alot for your help.
Can you please summarize what happened and how should i know how BUILD.xml works, that would be great. :)

Comment: First of all, you defined additional ant task, called testng, from Selenium testng Library, then you fixed task name, which seems was wrong in your example. There is only one way to check, whether your build is working - to check the expected results are done and no fails happend. As there are no fails, you should check the results you expected from this example from internet.